# Is it possible for me to refer to the key in this context?

Tags: javascript

So I have a data structure like

```
    this.PauseFunctions = {
        2: {
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the 2-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the 2-second mark was called");
            }
        },
        5: {
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the 5-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the 5-second mark was called");
            }
        }
    };
```

and I'm wondering if its possible for me to refer to the key whose value is the object containing the `OnSlideTo` function. For example, in

```
        2: {
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the 2-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the 2-second mark was called");
            }
        }
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to change it to

```
        2: {
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the " + key + "-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the " key + "-second mark was called");
            }
        }
```

where `key` is `2` so that my program can be more general and maintainable.

Comment: That is not possible due to the way each object is evaluated.

Comment: Why do you need tree functions where they are then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you will have to do it after the values are defined and then seed the key value. It shouldn't be too complicated, just a simple for loop once the keys are populated.

```js
var temp = new function(){

    this.PauseFunctions = {
        2: {
            //Key:,
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the "+this.Key+"-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the "+this.Key+"-second mark was called");
            }
        },
        5: {
            //Key:,
            OnSlideTo: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideTo function of the event at the "+this.Key+"-second mark was called");
            },
            OnSlideAway: function () {
                console.log("The OnSlideAway function of the event at the "+this.Key+"-second mark was called");
            }
        }
    };

    //seed key value
    for(var key in this.PauseFunctions){
        this.PauseFunctions[key].Key = key;
    }
};
temp.PauseFunctions[2].OnSlideTo();
```